# Sort a list of tuples alphabetically (case-sensitive)

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples

```
alist = [(u'First', 23), (u'Second', 64),(u'last', 19)]
```

I want to sort alphabetically (and case-sensitive) to get this:

```
(u'last', 19), (u'First', 23), (u'Second', 64)
```

I tried this:

```
sorted(alist, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse= True)
```

Unfortunately I get this:

```
(u'last', 19), (u'Second', 64), (u'First', 23),
```

Answer (score 9):

Include a key that indicates if the first character is uppercase or not:

```
>>> sorted([(u'First', 23), (u'Second', 64),(u'last', 19)], key=lambda t: (t[0][0].isupper(), t[0]))
[(u'last', 19), (u'First', 23), (u'Second', 64)]
```

`False` sorts before `True` so words with a lowercase initial will be sorted before words with a capital initial. Words are otherwise sorted lexicographically.

Comment: This won't properly sort based on the second and subsequent characters in the string.

Comment: This will fail for something like `last` and `laSt`.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: That depends entirely on what the OP is *expecting* from sorting data that has uppercase characters in the input strings beyond the first.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own sort function:

Characters are compared by their ascii values and therefore `'A'`(65) is always smaller than `'a'`(97), but you can change this by returning smaller value for `'a'` compared to `'A'`.

```
In [39]: lis=[(u'First', 23),(u'laSt',1), (u'Second', 64),(u'last', 19),(u'FirSt',5)]

In [40]: def mysort(x):
    elem=x[0]
    return [ord(x)-97 if x.islower() else ord(x)  for x in elem]
   ....: 

In [41]: sorted(lis,key=mysort)
Out[41]: [(u'last', 19), (u'laSt', 1), (u'First', 23), (u'FirSt', 5), (u'Second', 64)]
```

Comment: And what makes your output the correct sort? Why not sort `'FirSt'` last? It has more uppercase letters than `'Second'` has.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because alphabetically `'S'` comes after `'F'`, so there's no need to check other letters.

Comment: My point is that that is your interpretation. There could be others, we do not have enough example data to determine that.